# Separate letters and digits using regex with pandas

Tags: python, regex, string, pandas

I have a column called 'value' from a pandas dataframe, df, that has a mixture of numbers and words. It looks something like this:

```
   VALUE
0   done
1   Yes
2   3.45
3   2bc
```

I want to split the column up to 2 columns where the left one only has letters and the right one only numbers. Ideally, the result should be:

```
     0    1
0   done NaN
1   Yes  NaN
2   NaN  3.45
3   bc   2
```

I tried using the .str.extract pandas function like so:

```
df['value'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]+)')
```

The result I get is similar to the following:

```
    0    1
0   NaN NaN
1   NaN NaN
2   NaN 3.45
3   NaN NaN
```

where the words do not show up in column 0 as they should.

Does anyone know the reason why or a better way to do such an operation in pandas/python?

Comment: This gets messy very quickly.  What happens if a string has a number in the middle of it, e.g. `1b3` ?

Comment: For your specific example change `+` to `*` like `df['value'].str.extract('([A-Za-z]+)?([0-9]*[.]?[0-9]*)')`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix your pattern, and use `str.extractall`:

```
(df.VALUE.str.extractall('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)|([^\d.]+)')
   .unstack()
   .groupby(level=0, axis=1)
   .first())

      0     1
0   NaN  done
1   NaN   Yes
2  3.45   NaN
3     2    bc
```